# How to remove yellow circle in edit mode interface?

Tags: interface

Super newbie question. I accidentally pressed something on my keyboard and now every time I go to edit mode, there's this yellow circle thing that won't disappear. How do I remove it?

[image]

Comment: check you tools panel (T, on the left of the 3D view), maybe you've enable the Inset tool, click on another one (Move)

Comment: thank you so much T_T

Answer (score 2):

if you select a tool on the toolbar,this handle(yellow circle) appears.You can use the tool by pulling this handle.To swich back to selection click the icon on the top of the toolbar.
[image: the toolbar]